# Is there any way to add a user space to an Azure account?

Tags: azure

I know it is possible to add co-administrators to my subscription but I can't find any way to add a user space. I mean something that would allow users to see only their own storage and services created within the subscription.

I'm not worried about usage quotas but just would like to separate my users into distinct areas, so they don't interfere with each other.

Is there any way to do/achieve that?

Cheers,
  Jacek

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently in a subscription it is not possible to do so in Windows Azure. One possible solution would be to create separate subscription for each user and make them co-administrator on that subscription so that they will only see that subscription. This will obviously add more management headaches for you.

Again, not a fool-proof solution but when we were developing [**`Azure Management Studio`**](http://www.cerebrata.com) at Cerebrata (**Disclosure** - I was Founder of Cerebrata though now I'm not associated with it), we came up with something called `Profiles`. Basically what you do is put some resources (like storage accounts, cloud services etc.) and grant permissions on these resources in a profile and save that profile. You can then distribute this profile file to your user. When they run Azure Management Studio, they can load this profile file and will only see the things you included in that profile file. Again it is very specific to the tool only, is not as comprehensive as it does not include everything that Windows Azure offers and as and when you change storage credentials etc., you would need to regenerate that profile file.

Comment: I was afraid that's the current status. Thank you for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

**No that is not possible.**

The Co-Admins have complete control for the services in the account (non billing) as a whole and all the Services (Storage, Virtual Machine, Websites etc) are equally accessible to every administrator and co-administrator.